# How to store ion-range slider value in local storage on change using ionic-v4?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I want to store ion-range value in local storage on change. Like when we slide value will save/store in local storage. I try this way but it wasn't working.

page.ts

```js
    import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

    constructor(private storage: Storage){}

    initialtimeDelay(rangeValue) {
      console.log(rangeValue.detail.value);
      this.initialtimedelay = this.rangeValue;
      this.storage.set('initialtimeDelay', rangeValue.detail.value);
    }
```

page.html

```html
    <ion-range (ionChange)="initialtimeDelay($event)" [(ngModel)]="sliderrange" min="0" max="10" pin="true">
    </ion-range>
```

if add like this it's working good:

```
localStorage.setItem('initialtimeDelay', rangeValue.detail.value);
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

its pretty heavy to call async storage on every value change.

Try using ionBlur to only save range value upon release of focus from range element:

```
<ion-range (ionBlur)="initialtimeDelay($event)" [(ngModel)]="sliderrange" min="0" max="10" pin="true">
    </ion-range>
```

Comment: @user9088454 can you specify what is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

I just refresh local storage and this code is fine and it's working. sorry, my bad :)